# MVC3 MapRoute, how to

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url, routes

I am looking at creating some new routes within my MVC3 application. What I want is a route that will allow me to produce:

```
{clientname}/{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

Where I am unsure is whether or not I should make use of the object defaults parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add the following route definition:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ClientRoute",
    "{clientname}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Because `clientname` is at the beginning it is a compulsory value. It must always be specified and cannot be empty.

For example if you generate an anchor:

```
@Html.ActionLink("link text", "Foo", new { clientname = "bar" })
```

it would produce the following output:

```
<a href="/bar/Home/Foo">link text</a>
```